# Sending back a file stream from GRPC Python Server

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

I have a service that needs to return a filestream to the calling client so I have created this proto file.

```
service Sample {
     rpc getSomething(Request) returns (stream Response){}
}

message Request {

}

message Response {
    bytes data = 1;
}
```

When the server receives this, it needs to read some source.txt file and then write it back to the client
as a byte stream.  Just would like to ask is this the proper way to do this in a Python GRPC server?

```
fileName = "source.txt"
with open(file_name, 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
    response.data = content.encode()
    yield response
```

I cannot find any examples related to this.

Comment: https://ops.tips/blog/sending-files-via-grpc/

Comment: Thanks Mate..I can't understand C language.. I am really new to Python also.. but is what I am doing correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks mostly correct, though it's hard to be sure since you haven't shared with us all of your service-side code. A few tweaks I'd suggest would be (1) reading the file as binary content in the first place, (2) exiting the `with` statement as early as possible, (3) constructing the response message only after you've constructed the value of its `data` field, and (4) making a module-scope module-private constant out of the file name. Something like:

```
with open(_CONTENT_FILE_NAME, 'rb') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
yield my_generated_module_pb2.Response(data=content)
```

. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to lazily read in the binary and yield each chunk.  Note, this is untested code:

```
def read_bytes(file_, num_bytes):
    while True:
        bin = file_.read(num_bytes)
        if len(bin) != num_bytes:
            break
        yield bin   

class ResponseStreamer(Sample_pb2_grpc.SampleServicer):
    def getSomething(request, context):
        with open('test.bin', 'rb') as f:
            for rec in read_bytes(f, 4):
                yield Sample_pb2.Response(data=rec)
```

Downside is that you'll have the file opened while the stream is open.